# Set Variable for Select Result in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL statement like these:

```
DECLARE @bDate DATE;
SET @bDate = SELECT birth_date FROM person WHERE id='1';

SELECT @bDate;
```

But the result always is an error:

> Must Declare the scalar variable for @bDate

Can anyone help me? I have asked from any forum but the result are same.

Thanks

Comment: if `id` is of type `int` then drop the quotes around the `'1'` and then check out the answer below

Comment: I am wondering why you didn't get the error "`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'`"

Comment: if I execute with navicat, I only got error Scalar variable, but if I execute with SQL Management Studio, I got `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'`. however, from now I'll use sql management studio If i must use variable on my query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for the `SET`

It should be

```
DECLARE @bDate DATE;
SET @bDate = (SELECT birth_date FROM person WHERE id='1');

SELECT @bDate;
```

OR, you can use `SELECT`

```
DECLARE @bDate DATE;
SELECT @bDate = birth_date FROM person WHERE id='1';

SELECT @bDate;
```

Comment: I've tried, but still error. is it related to the SQL Server version? I'm using SqlServer 13.0.4001.0.

Comment: no. it does not. are you using the exact query as i have posted ? If not please update your original question with that query and also the error message

Comment: hmmm.. I knew, it turns out the error is because of using (Interface) Navicat.
If I use SQL Management Studio, the query is work. Thank you @Squirrel.

Comment: I know where's the problem here: https://forums.asp.net/t/1868579.aspx?+Err+42000+SQL+Server+Must+declare+the+scalar+variable